# What is the average time?

Tags: probability

Probability to wait more than 0.45 ms for an application to start is 0.54.
What is the average time to wait for the application to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided sufficient information to answer that question. All you can say is that the average waiting time is at least (0.54x0.45)ms.

Comment: That's all the question. The answers are A) 0.85269 B) 1.92846 C) 1.67796 D) 0.74763 E) 0.73

Comment: @user1070228 You must be missing some details in the question.  Consider two scenarios:  In scenario A we have that with probability 0.54 the application takes exactly 0.4500001ms to load and with the remaining probability the application takes zero time to load.  Here, the average waiting time is about 0.243 ms.  Scenario B we have that with probability 0.54 the application takes a million years to load and with the remaining probability takes 0.4ms to load.  Here, the average waiting time is *much* larger.  Both scenarios match your question.

Comment: This was a question from an exam. I just translated it in english. I thought there was a way to solve it with just this information, but I guess the question was wrong. Thank you for answering.